# Floating thumbnails next to titles

Tags: css, html, imageview, title

i don't understand why some of the thumbnails appear differently while they have the same css...

```
h4 { line-height:100%; color: #be2d30; letter-spacing: 1px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'Gnuolane'; font-size:26px; line-height:10%; } div.container {  } div.left {    width: 45%;     float: left; } div.right {  width: 54%;     float: right; }#thumb { display:inline; vertical-align:bottom; float:right; height:30px; width:30px; }
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right">
<img id="thumb"src="http://www.lubika.co.il/wp-content/uploads/icons-6-150x150.jpg" >
<h4>סדנת ציורי גוף אמנותיים עם רותם לוץ-אמנית איפור בינלאומית</h4>
מרץ 6 @ 10:00-13:00

<img id="thumb" alt="" src="http://www.lubika.co.il/wp-content/uploads/icons-10.jpg" />
<h4>מפגש סוכנות-השתלמות ציורי פנים לקראת פורים</h4>
מרץ 9 @ 10:00-13:00

</div>
<div class="left"><img id="thumb" alt="" src="http://www.lubika.co.il/wp-content/uploads/icons-9.jpg" />
<h4>מפגש סוכנות-השתלמות איפור כלות טבעיות</h4>
מרץ 23 @ 10:00-13:00

<br><br>

<img id="thumb" alt="" src="http://www.lubika.co.il/wp-content/uploads/icons-8.jpg" />
<h4>תרגול חופשי של איפור</h4>
מרץ 30 @ 16:00-20:00

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "differently"? They look the same to me.

Answer (score 1):

`#thumb`:  should be a div '**class**', not div '**id**'.
 Meaning, you are using your `#thumb` multiple times.  A div '**id**', you can only use **once** within a page.
A *div class="thumb"* selector can be used multiple times within a single page.

```
.thumb {
   display:inline;
   /* etc */
}
```

Also in your code I see you have line-height twice.

```
h4 {
   line-height: 100%;
   line-height: 10%;
}
```

It would have been easier to evaluate, if you had put your code in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: hey, thank you! i have changed it. but it still looks like this: http://www.lubika.co.il/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F/
(not the same in all titles)

Comment: can you please take a look? http://www.lubika.co.il/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F/

Comment: I see the thumbnails too attached to the text.  Try changing the 'left' width: 65%; and 'right' width: 30%;.  See if it will make a difference.  I am testing your code on [link] http://jsfiddle.net/f2a7v/ .

Comment: If it does not look good, use the 'un-ordered list' method, by putting **Text** and **Thumbnail** side-by-side.  Same for the text and thumbnail underneath.